Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
This is an SQL code I used. It works fine until I introduct this line:
case when `USFacilitywithType`.`Category`='Type 3' then round(`USFacilitywithType`.`netprice` * `USFacilityPriceWithDisc`.`PriceLevel`,2) else round(`USFacilitywithType`.`netprice` * 1) end AS `Discounted Price`


Originally, it was :
`netprice` * `USFacilityPriceWithDisc`.`PriceLevel`,2) AS `Discounted Price`

    select  `USFacilitywithType`.`unitno` AS `Unitno`,`USFacilitywithType`.`description` AS `description`,
            `USFacilitywithType`.`size` AS `size`,`USFacilitywithType`.`netprice` AS `netprice`,
            case when `USFacilitywithType`.`Category`='Type 3' then round(`USFacilitywithType`.`netprice` * `USFacilityPriceWithDisc`.`PriceLevel`,
                    2) else round(`USFacilitywithType`.`netprice` * 1
                              ) end AS `Discounted Price`,
            `USFacilitywithType`.`Maintenance` AS `Maintenance`,`USFacilitywithType`.`zone` AS `Zone`,
            case when `USFacilitywithType`.`unitno` like '%/A/%' then 'Aircon' else 'Non-Aircon' end AS `Type`
        from  (`ustoreat_ecomm`.`USFacilitywithType`
        join  `ustoreat_ecomm`.`USFacilityPriceWithDisc` on(`USFacilitywithType`.`Category` = `USFacilityPriceWithDisc`.`Type`)
              )


I get 


#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

I have changed the database and tables to collation to utf8mb4_general_ci but the error persists.
`USFacilitywithType` and USFacilityPriceWithDisc as views if that makes a difference.


As above. I was hoping to hardcode the value in the Discounted Price except for Type 3 which should  use the value from the view USFacilityPriceWithDisc.


Did you change the columns and the connection?
